# How to Update missing data in an MS Access table based on data from that same table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of health plan subscribers we'll call it `table1`.  Members are listed multiple times as all of their benefits are listed (`Plan Name` field).  In some cases they may have an address listed for one `Plan Name` and not for the other.  I'm blanking on how to create an update query that will fill in the `Street Address 1`, `Street Address 2`, `City`, `State`, and `Zip Code` based on the same fields that they have listed for another `Plan Name` in the same table?  I can identify the members by their `Member_ID`

Comment: This data is not normalized. You should have a table of members with address info and each member would be a unique record (listed only once). Then have a related table for Plans. Otherwise, build a query that pulls address info as a DISTINCT record for each member. Apply filter criteria to exclude records where Zip Code is Null. This basically emulates the Members table I describe. Use this as the source to update records lacking the address info.

Comment: I built this database quickly as a way to put together a one time report for a client.  I was thinking there might be a way to do a self join to update the missing information.  I guess I could've make another table with each members SSN and their Address and then apply an update query to the original table.  I just thought there might be a way to skip a step.

Comment: You need a dataset of unique member records (table or query). Build query that emulates the missing table and use that as source for UPDATE action. Or better, use it to fix db structure.

Comment: However, I just remembered that UPDATE action requires an 'updatable' table/query as source. Aggregate queries are not updatable. Now I think you really will have to create the table. Or write a VBA procedure to accomplish.

Comment: And this all assumes the address info for each member are consistent across records, except for the ones where there is no address data at all. If there is any variation in spelling (St instead of Street, etc), you will not get a unique record for each member. Cleaning up this bad data will be a tedious, time-consuming, aggravating effort. A unique dataset is needed because otherwise how should Access know which record to use as the UPDATE source if member has more than one? Access would likely use the last record read for each member, which may be adequate for your needs.

Comment: So make a copy of db and try the self-join update. What happens?

Comment: I ended up just quickly making a separate table with the address and the members SSN, then updated the main table from the new table.  Was actually very quick and easy.  Thanks to all who responded!

Answer (score 0):

Using most of the comments and suggestions above:
If you link the table to itself:

```
SELECT Parent.*, table1.PlanName AS Plan FROM table1 AS Parent 
    LEFT JOIN table1 on Parent.Member_ID = table1.Member_ID
WHERE Parent.zipcode is not null
```

This should get what you have asked for!